# Rspec not matching my route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I have `post '/foo/bar', to: 'api/v1/things#bar'` in my `routes.rb`.

Running `rails routes` returns

```
foo_bar POST /foo/bar(.:format) api/v1/things#bar
```

I'm trying to test it with `post '/foo/bar'`, but I get

```
No route matches {:action=>"/foo/bar", :controller=>"api/v1/things"}
```

I know the problem is something silly, but I'm unable to see it. Any ideas?

Comment: Which kind of test is this? controller test?

Comment: Yes, a contoroller test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routing is not a thing when you run controller specs.

Use:

```
post 'bar'
```

Very likely there is `describe API::V1:Things do` around this test, this  tells RSpec which controller to use.

Answer (score 1):

In a controller test, you should use actual action name, `bar`. Routing details is none of controller's business. This is a focused test, so test only the controller logic.

Integration tests, on the other hand, is a different beast. They by definition test the whole stack (because of this, they are also called "end to end tests"). You should be able to post to `/foo/bar` in a feature spec, because request will go through router.